# Using XSL to style a XML with multiple XInclude

Tags: xml, xslt, xinclude

I am trying to style a XML document that uses xinclude to include other xml files for modularity purposes.
I'm using Firefox as my tool to visualize the transformation. (All the files are in the same folder)
At the moment i have composed the following xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                          xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
                          exclude-result-prefixes='xsl xi'>
    <xsl:template match="/interfaces">
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8" content="text/html" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
                <title>Messages</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="message"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="message">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/><br/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="xi:include[@href][@parse='xml' or not(@parse)]" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xi:include">
        Should be outputed...<xsl:apply-templates select="document(@href)" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet
```

To process the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='messages-xsl.xml'?>

<interfaces>
    <message name="some_message">
        <xi:include href="some_message.xml" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2003/XInclude"/>
    </message>
</interfaces>
```

I know that some posts on stackoverflow ask similar questions but i couldn't fix the problem so far.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XSLT has `xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"`, yet your sample has `xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2003/XInclude"`, you will need to use the same namespace in both XSLT and XML. And for better error messages I would suggest to use `version="1.0"` in XSLT as Firefox uses an XSLT 1.0 processor and is switched to forwards compatible processing with your version="2.0" attribute.

Comment: +1: While I'm still trying to find the question in the post Martin has already supplied the answer!